# Using a closure as while loop condition in struct's method which requires a reference to self, in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a simple struct `Parser`

```rust
pub struct Parser {
    pos: usize,
    input: String,
}
```

I'm trying to build a markdown parser and there's a method `parse_md_line` which contains a while loop and I'm trying to make the while loop's condition dynamic based on `delimiter` value

```
pub fn parse_md_line(&mut self, delimiter: Option<char>) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();

    let mut cond: Box<dyn Fn() -> bool> = Box::new(|| {
        return self.pos < self.input.len()
            && (self.next_char() != '\n' || utils::is_whitespace(self.next_char()));
    });

    if delimiter.is_some() {
        cond = Box::new(|| {
            return self.pos < self.input.len() && self.next_char() != delimiter.unwrap();
        });
    }

    while cond() {
        let normal_text = self.parse_alpha_numeric(true); // this mutates `self`
        .....
    }
 
  result
 }
```

while loop's inner working are hidden as they do matter much, but it calls some methods, which mutates `self`.

This code throw error for `let normal_text = self.parse_alpha_numeric(true);`,
**cannot borrow *self as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable.

I understand the error and why it's happening. But cannot figure out a way to work it out. I hit and tried using `RefCell`, `Rc` still nothing of use.

Maybe It can be done using `RefCell`, from what I've tried the code grew unnecessary complex.

Is there a standard or cleaner way to handle things like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple issues here:

1. `Fn` can't modify it's environment, you could change it to `FnMut` but
2. you're creating multiple closures that want to hold a mutable reference to self simultaneously but `&mut self` can only be held once
3. you want to modify `self` while the closure holds on to a exclusive reference, you can't create multiple exclusive references to self though.

To solve them you can make `self` a parameter for the closure, that way it doesn't need to capture `self`, or hold on to it across the loop body, it also doesn't need to be a `FnMut` because you don't modify the environment any longer:

```rust
pub fn parse_md_line(&mut self, delimiter: Option<char>) {
    let cond: Box<dyn Fn(&mut Self) -> bool> = if let Some(delimiter) = delimiter {
        Box::new(move |this| this.pos < this.input.len() && this.next_char() != delimiter)
    } else {
        Box::new(|this| this.pos < this.input.len() && !this.next_char().is_whitespace())
    };
    while cond(self) {
        let _normal_text = self.parse_alpha_numeric(true); // this mutates `self`
    }
}
```

You can also just write the condition inline to avoid any allocation of a closure and the complete problem, the compiler is clever enough to optimize the `if` check to ahead of the loop:

```rust
pub fn parse_md_line(&mut self, delimiter: Option<char>) {
    while self.pos < self.input.len()
        && if let Some(delimiter) = delimiter {
            self.next_char() != delimiter
        } else {
            !self.next_char().is_whitespace()
        }
    {
        let _normal_text = self.parse_alpha_numeric(true); // this mutates `self`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can avoid using methods of `Self` in the closure.

```
pub fn parse_md_line(&mut self, delimiter: Option<char>) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();
    let mut check_delimiter: Box<dyn Fn(char) -> bool> = match delimiter {
        Some(delimiter) => Box::new(move |c| {
            c != delimiter
        }),
        None => Box::new(|c| {
            c != '\n' /* || utils::is_whitespace(self.next_char()) */
        })
    };
    while self.pos < self.input.len() && check_delimiter(self.next_char()) {
        let _normal_text = self.parse_alpha_numeric(true);
    }
    result
}
```

Also, with such an approach, you can avoid using the `.unwrap()` in the code.
[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a140b998e770113af0cd1a3afe51756) link.